# Send spacebar to other application

Tags: c#, process, space, sendkeys

I have a problem with sending spacebar to another application (GAME)

While this code works for input (even in GAME) it doesn't simulate key_pressed action.
I'm using C# with .Net Framework 4.5.

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("game").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null)
{
    IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;

    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ }");
}
```

I have tried with:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{ }");

SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
```

If I choose Notepad it works, it also works if I have focus (in GAME) on some input, e.g. textbox chat, but when in game I'm asked to press space bar (Press Spacebar to continue) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that most games make use of [DirectInput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput). So the standard windows messages for key handling is bypassed. You will have to use DirectX codes. Here is some code from my voice recognition application that sends keys to games that can help you:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BlueMercs.Core.Services
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MouseInput
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public int mouseData;
        public int dwFlags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct KeyboardInput
    {
        public short wVk;      //Virtual KeyCode (not needed here)
        public short wScan;    //Directx Keycode 
        public int dwFlags;    //This tells you what is use (Keyup, Keydown..)
        public int time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct HardwareInput
    {
        public int uMsg;
        public short wParamL;
        public short wParamH;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct Input
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int type;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public MouseInput mi;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public KeyboardInput ki;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public HardwareInput hi;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum KeyFlag
    {       
        KeyDown = 0x0000,
        ExtendedKey = 0x0001,
        KeyUp = 0x0002,
        UniCode = 0x0004,
        ScanCode = 0x0008
    }

    public static class WindowsMessageService
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 nInputs,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] Input[] pInputs, Int32 cbSize);

        public static void SendInput(short keycode, KeyFlag keyFlag)
        {
            var inputData = new Input[1];

            inputData[0].type = 1;
            inputData[0].ki.wScan = keycode;
            inputData[0].ki.dwFlags = (int)keyFlag;
            inputData[0].ki.time = 0;
            inputData[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

            SendInput(1, inputData, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Input)));
        }

        public static void SendKey(short keyCode, KeyFlag keyFlag)
        {
            SendInput(keyCode, keyFlag | KeyFlag.ScanCode);
        }
    }
}



    public class DirectxKey
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public int Decimal { get; set; }
        public short Hex { get; set; }
    }


    public static class DirectxService
    {
        private static readonly List<DirectxKey> _keys;

        static DirectxService()
        {
            _keys = new List<DirectxKey>
                {
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "[", Decimal = 26, Hex = 0x1A},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "'", Decimal = 40, Hex = 0x28},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "]", Decimal = 27, Hex = 0x1B},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "/", Decimal = 53, Hex = 0x35},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = ";", Decimal = 39, Hex = 0x27},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = ".", Decimal = 52, Hex = 0x34},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "-", Decimal = 12, Hex = 0x0C},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = @"\", Decimal = 43, Hex = 0x2B},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = ",", Decimal = 51, Hex = 0x33},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "=", Decimal = 13, Hex = 0x0D},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "`", Decimal = 41, Hex = 0x29},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "0", Decimal = 11, Hex = 0x0B},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "1", Decimal = 2, Hex = 0x02},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "2", Decimal = 3, Hex = 0x03},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "3", Decimal = 4, Hex = 0x04},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "4", Decimal = 5, Hex = 0x05},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "5", Decimal = 6, Hex = 0x06},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "6", Decimal = 7, Hex = 0x07},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "7", Decimal = 8, Hex = 0x08},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "8", Decimal = 9, Hex = 0x09},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "9", Decimal = 10, Hex = 0x0A},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "A", Decimal = 30, Hex = 0x1E},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "B", Decimal = 48, Hex = 0x38},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "C", Decimal = 14, Hex = 0x2E},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "CAPSLOCK", Decimal = 58, Hex = 0x3A},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "D", Decimal = 32, Hex = 0x20},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "DOWN", Decimal = 208, Hex = 0xD0},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "E", Decimal = 18, Hex = 0x12},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "ENTER", Decimal = 28, Hex = 0x1C},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "ESCAPE", Decimal = 1, Hex = 0x01},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F", Decimal = 33, Hex = 0x21},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F1", Decimal = 059, Hex = 0x3B},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F10", Decimal = 068, Hex = 0x44},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F11", Decimal = 087, Hex = 0x57},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F12", Decimal = 088, Hex = 0x58},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F2", Decimal = 060, Hex = 0x3C},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F3", Decimal = 061, Hex = 0x3D},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F4", Decimal = 062, Hex = 0x3E},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F5", Decimal = 063, Hex = 0x3F},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F6", Decimal = 064, Hex = 0x40},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F7", Decimal = 065, Hex = 0x41},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F8", Decimal = 066, Hex = 0x42},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "F9", Decimal = 067, Hex = 0x43},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "G", Decimal = 034, Hex = 0x22},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "H", Decimal = 035, Hex = 0x23},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "I", Decimal = 023, Hex = 0x17},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "J", Decimal = 036, Hex = 0x24},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "K", Decimal = 037, Hex = 0x25},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "L", Decimal = 038, Hex = 0x26},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "LEFTALT", Decimal = 056, Hex = 0x38},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "LEFTARROW", Decimal = 203, Hex = 0xCB},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "LEFTCTRL", Decimal = 029, Hex = 0x1D},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "LEFTMB", Decimal = 256, Hex = 0x100},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "LEFTSHIFT", Decimal = 042, Hex = 0x2A},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "M", Decimal = 050, Hex = 0x32},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "MIDDLEMB", Decimal = 258, Hex = 0x102},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "MB3", Decimal = 259, Hex = 0x103},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "MB4", Decimal = 260, Hex = 0x104},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "MB5", Decimal = 261, Hex = 0x105},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "MB6", Decimal = 262, Hex = 0x106},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "MB7", Decimal = 263, Hex = 0x107},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "MOUSEWHEELDOWN", Decimal = 265, Hex = 0x109},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "MOUSEWHEELUP", Decimal = 264, Hex = 0x108},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "N", Decimal = 049, Hex = 0x31},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM*", Decimal = 055, Hex = 0x37},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM-", Decimal = 074, Hex = 0x4A},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM/", Decimal = 181, Hex = 0xB5},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM.", Decimal = 083, Hex = 0x53},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM+", Decimal = 078, Hex = 0x4E},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM0", Decimal = 082, Hex = 0x52},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM1", Decimal = 079, Hex = 0x4F},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM2", Decimal = 080, Hex = 0x50},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM3", Decimal = 081, Hex = 0x52},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM4", Decimal = 075, Hex = 0x4B},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM5", Decimal = 076, Hex = 0x4C},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM6", Decimal = 077, Hex = 0x4D},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM7", Decimal = 071, Hex = 0x48},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM8", Decimal = 072, Hex = 0x47},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUM9", Decimal = 073, Hex = 0x49},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUMENTER", Decimal = 156, Hex = 0x9C},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "NUMLOCK", Decimal = 069, Hex = 0x45},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "O", Decimal = 024, Hex = 0x18},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "P", Decimal = 025, Hex = 0x19},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "Q", Decimal = 016, Hex = 0x10},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "R", Decimal = 019, Hex = 0x13},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "RIGHTALT", Decimal = 184, Hex = 0xB8},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "RIGHTARROW", Decimal = 205, Hex = 0xCD},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "RIGHTCTRL", Decimal = 157, Hex = 0x9D},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "RIGHTMB", Decimal = 257, Hex = 0x101},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "RIGHTSHIFT", Decimal = 054, Hex = 0x36},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "S", Decimal = 031, Hex = 0x1F},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "SCROLLLOCK", Decimal = 070, Hex = 0x46},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "SPACEBAR", Decimal = 057, Hex = 0x39},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "T", Decimal = 020, Hex = 0x14},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "TAB", Decimal = 015, Hex = 0x0F},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "U", Decimal = 022, Hex = 0x16},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "UPARROW", Decimal = 200, Hex = 0xC8},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "V", Decimal = 047, Hex = 0x2F},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "W", Decimal = 017, Hex = 0x11},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "X", Decimal = 045, Hex = 0x2D},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "Y", Decimal = 021, Hex = 0x15},
                    new DirectxKey {Key = "Z", Decimal = 044, Hex = 0x2C}
                };
        }

        public static DirectxKey GetDirectxKey(string key)
        {
            var result = _keys.Find(mapKey => mapKey.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            return result;
        }

        public static List<DirectxKey> Keys { get { return _keys; } }

    }
}
```

Comment: Any other ideas? I really would like to use something more uviersal.

Comment: There are no shortcuts, you will have to get your hands dirty. You mean universal? Meaning different platforms?

Comment: Different than DirectX - opengl, standard window application etc.